# How can I check out the Delphi demos from Sourceforge?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

The [Delphi DocWiki page for Code Examples](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/Main_Page)  points to http://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/ as the address for "RAD Studio demos and samples in the Sourceforge Subversion repository".

On this page there is a web view of the Subversion folders.

But which address do I need for the Subversion checkout operation?

Answer (score 1):

The checkout URL is

https://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/radstudiodemos/trunk

Comment: Note that this points to the current demo apps for Delphi XE. For future releases, there might be branched versions in https://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/radstudiodemos/branches

Comment: Can someone explain to me why there are so few demos for XE7? Why have the demos from XE 6 (https://svn.code.sf.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/branches/RadStudio_XE6/Object%20Pascal/VCL/) been removed in XE7 (https://svn.code.sf.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/branches/RadStudio_XE7/Object%20Pascal/VCL/)?